# Force single-threaded ANN training

Tags: java, multithreading, neural-network, encog

I have a `BasicNetwork` that I will use in ensemble learning. I appreciate Encog's multithreaded training that it uses by default for neural networks, but how can I configure the network or the trainer to train on a single thread only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Encog 3.3, you can use the [`setThreadCount`](http://heatonresearch-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/javadoc/encog-3.3/org/encog/neural/networks/training/propagation/Propagation.html#setThreadCount(int)) method like this

```
Propagation train = new Propagation(network,data);
train.setThreadCount(1);
```